# error 255 when flashing zip

Tags: twrp, zip

so yes: today i was trying to test my own zip (yes, twrp) but when i tried it thrown me error

`updater process ended with ERROR:255`

`error installing zip file '/emmc/recovery.zip'`

is it because i messed up that zip, i dont have many space on phone or another thing?

my device is lg l65 d280n and zip is there : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GbHeXDbs1Dh9G-FPw82hNJY9kc03hOBb/view?usp=drivesdk .

PS: i know that here is a few similar questions but no, i dont have that second error "createtarfork()" but yes - i have cyanogenmod 14 which is nearby lineage, which is buggy as i heard.

Comment: error 255 itself is meaningless, probably related to C language return -1 it just tell you that something is wrong. could be failed to create file, file does not exist, library missing, can't execute, wrong arch, aborted, no disk space or any meaning, so only you can know the context

Comment: ? Strange i uploaded this file... and okay, i’ll debug. Thanks.    Edit: reuploaded file, should work i think...